# Get people in all tenants

Tags: java, alfresco, multi-tenant

I try to count the people in all tenants using a Java web script. This web script shall be invoked as the admin user of the default tenant and collect people statistics for each tenant.

I struggle to get the people for a tenant. The methods `countPeople()` and `getAllPeople()` of `org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PersonService` always give me only the people in the *default tenant*, even though I wrap this call in `AuthenticationUtil.runAs(...)`.

```
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationContext;
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil;
import org.alfresco.repo.tenant.MultiTAdminServiceImpl;
import org.alfresco.repo.tenant.Tenant;
import org.alfresco.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PersonService;

// ...

protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest req, Status status) {
    final Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
    final Map<String, Map<String, Long>> tenantNameToTenantData = new HashMap<>();
    if (tenantAdminService != null) {
        for (final Tenant tenant : tenantAdminService.getAllTenants()) {
            final String tenantDomain = tenant.getTenantDomain();
            final String systemUserName = authenticationContext.getSystemUserName(tenantDomain);

            final Map<String, Long> tenantData = AuthenticationUtil.runAs(() -> {
                final Map<String, Long> td = new HashMap<>();
                final long userCount = (long) personService.countPeople();
                td.put("userCount", userCount);

                long totalUsage = 0L;
                for (NodeRef personNodeRef : personService.getAllPeople()) {
                    totalUsage += (long) serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getProperty(personNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_SIZE_CURRENT);
                }
                totalUsage = totalUsage / (1_024L * 1_024L);
                td.put("totalUsage", totalUsage);
                return td;
            }, systemUserName);

            tenantNameToTenantData.put(tenantDomain, tenantData);
        }
    }
    model.put("tenants", tenantNameToTenantData);
    return model;
}
```

The call to `authenticationContext.getSystemUserName(tenantDomain)` returns the correct names (`System@tenant1`, ...).

How can I get the people for each tenant without having to explicitly authenticate as the tenant admin?

Comment: Use [TenantUtil.runAsTenant](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/data-model/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/tenant/TenantUtil.java#L82)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Gragravarr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr) for the hint to use [`TenantUtil.runAsTenant`](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/data-model/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/tenant/TenantUtil.java#L82). This is how it works:

```
final TenantUtil.TenantRunAsWork<Map<String, Long>> runAsWork = () -> {
    final Map<String, String> td = new HashMap<>();
    td.put("userCount", (long) personService.countPeople());

    long totalUsage = 0L;
    for (NodeRef personNodeRef : personService.getAllPeople()) {
        totalUsage += (long) serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getProperty(personNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_SIZE_CURRENT);
    }
    totalUsage = totalUsage / (1_024L * 1_024L);
    td.put("totalUsage", totalUsage);

    return td;
};
final Map<String, Long> tenantData =
    TenantUtil.runAsTenant(runAsWork, tenantDomain);
```